# How to export Estimator model with export_savedmodel function

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-serving

are there any tutorials available about `export_savedmodel` ?

I have gone through [this article](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/api_docs/python/contrib.learn/estimators) on tensorflow.org and [unittest code](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/05d7f793ec5f04cd6b362abfef620a78fefdb35f/tensorflow/python/estimator/estimator_test.py) on github.com, and still have no idea about how to construct the parameter `serving_input_fn` of function `export_savedmodel`

Comment: [Example of export_savedmodel function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48329456/4268517)

Comment: Check sol provided here
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58959582/saving-loading-and-predicting-from-a-tensorflow-estimator-model-2-0/60230173#comment118347400_60230173

Answer (score 13):

Do it like this:

```
your_feature_spec = {
    "some_feature": tf.FixedLenFeature([], dtype=tf.string, default_value=""),
    "some_feature": tf.VarLenFeature(dtype=tf.string),
}

def _serving_input_receiver_fn():
    serialized_tf_example = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.string, shape=None, 
                                           name='input_example_tensor')
    # key (e.g. 'examples') should be same with the inputKey when you 
    # buid the request for prediction
    receiver_tensors = {'examples': serialized_tf_example}
    features = tf.parse_example(serialized_tf_example, your_feature_spec)
    return tf.estimator.export.ServingInputReceiver(features, receiver_tensors)

estimator.export_savedmodel(export_dir, _serving_input_receiver_fn)
```

Then you can request the served model with "predict" signature name by batch.

Source: https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/saved_model#prepare_serving_inputs

Comment: using feature_spec = {'x': tf.FixedLenFeature([224, 224, 3], dtype=tf.float32)} i got the error: TypeError: Failed to convert object of type <type 'dict'> to Tensor

Comment: The signature is 'predict', is there a way to specify custom signature? Or set back to the 'serving_default'.

Answer (score 2):

if you are using tensorflow straight from the master branch there's a module tensorflow.python.estimator.export that provides a function for that:

```
from tensorflow.python.estimator.export import export
feature_spec = {'MY_FEATURE': tf.constant(2.0, shape=[1, 1])}
serving_input_fn = export.build_raw_serving_input_receiver_fn(feature_spec)
```

Unfortunately at least for me it will not go further than that but I'm not sure if my model is really correct so maybe you have more luck than I do.

Alternatively, there are the following functions for the current version installed from pypi:

```
serving_input_fn = tf.contrib.learn.utils.build_parsing_serving_input_fn(feature_spec)
serving_input_fn = tf.contrib.learn.utils.build_default_serving_input_fn(feature_spec)
```

But I couldn't get them to work, too.

Probably, I'm not understanding this correctly so I hope you'll have more luck.

chris

Answer (score 2):

You have 2 options:

### Export your model to work with JSON dictionaries

In my [mlengine-boilerplate repository](https://github.com/Fematich/mlengine-boilerplate/blob/master/trainer/task.py), I use this to export estimator models to Cloud ML Engine to easily use this with online predictions ([sample code for the predictions](https://github.com/Fematich/mlengine-boilerplate/blob/master/predictions/predict.py)). Essential part:

```
def serving_input_fn():
    feature_placeholders = {
        'id': tf.placeholder(tf.string, [None], name="id_placeholder"),
        'feat': tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, FEAT_LEN], name="feat_placeholder"),
        #label is not required since serving is only used for inference
    }
    return input_fn_utils.InputFnOps(
        feature_placeholders,
        None,
        feature_placeholders)
```

### Export your model to work with Tensorflow Examples

[This tutorial](https://github.com/MtDersvan/tf_playground/blob/master/wide_and_deep_tutorial/wide_and_deep_basic_serving.md) shows how you can use `export_savedmodel` to serve
   the Wide & Deep Model implemented with estimators and how to feed Tensorflow examples into the exported model. The essential
   part:

```
from tensorflow.contrib.learn.python.learn.utils import input_fn_utils      
serving_input_fn = input_fn_utils.build_parsing_serving_input_fn(feature_spec)
```

Comment: I updated the [tutorial](https://github.com/MtDersvan/tf_playground/blob/master/wide_and_deep_tutorial/wide_and_deep_basic_serving.md) to support r1.3. You should probably update your answer to reflect new changes.

Comment: @MtDersvan , in the tutorial: `np.argmax(prediction) ` .. I don't believe it is functioning as believed. For some reason, it is always giving 0 as response for any scores returned.
`type(prediction)` gives `tensorflow.core.framework.tensor_pb2.TensorProto` . How can we read this object?

Comment: For me if I update the code to `np.argmax(prediction.float_val)`, it works perfectly.

Comment: This was discussed in an issue here https://github.com/MtDersvan/tf_playground/issues/5. Exactly, you need an array of `float_val`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have tf.train.Example and tf.train.Feature and pass the input to input receiver function and invoke the model.
 You can take a look at this example
https://github.com/tettusud/tensorflow-examples/tree/master/estimators